# AngularJS download multiple files from checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new to angularJS and have come across a problem. I have a checkbox where a user can select all the checkboxes to download some files. The user can click on a button to download the selected files. I think it's probably something quite simple but I can't make it work. When I select all the checkboxes only the first file in the array is downloaded. I think I need to loop through the array, but I'm doing it wrong. Please if someone could make any suggestions/or help I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Here is the download button in the html:

```
<button type="submit" 
        ng-click="download()" 
        ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" 
        class="btn btn-success">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>&nbsp;Download</button>
```

And in the controller:

```
 $scope.download = function() {
        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/download?"+ $scope.selection)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            angular.forEach($scope.results, function (result) {  
            $scope.download.push("result.personName"+"result.&userId");    
            //alert("Downloaded!") 
            });
         }); 
     };
```

Comment: It may be tough to figure out without knowing how the `/download` resource works or what the format of `$scope.selection` is.

Comment: You didn't use data in success function! I think you have to iterate on data, not $scope.results.

Comment: Hi Alvin, yes sorry - the $scope.selection would contain the data of each individual checkbox that is selected.(result.personName"+"result.&userId)

Comment: Thanks alisabzevari. I'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: Actually what do you want? do you want to call multiple download apis?

Comment: Hi Simon, no I don't think so, I think t's just one API  - just want to be able to download all the files from the checkbox if selected all. I am able to successfully get one file, but not all ;(.

Answer (score 0):

I hope `$scope.selection` is an array, which you want to download.

```
$scope.download = function() {
   angular.forEach($scope.selection, function (value, key) {  
      $http.get("http://localhost:3000/download?"+ value)
      .success(function (result, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.downloadArray[key] = "result.personName"+"result.&userId";
      });
   });
};
```

Comment: Thank you simon. Unfortunately it doesn't work. So if I select one checkbox I get this "personName=Adrew-Black&userId=07609". Which is in the $scope.selection.

Comment: It work for one with this  $scope.download = function() {
      $http.get("http://localhost:3000/download?"+ $scope.selection[0])
       .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    
             });
       };

Comment: what happen if you click selectall check bok? Can you give me some more details for your question

Comment: Ok, so if there are 3 items in my results i.e three users I get this: ["personName=Adrew-Black&userId=07609"] ["personName=Jane-Wells&userId=07610"]  ["personName=John-Richards&userId=07611"]

Comment: so your $scope.selection = ["personName=Adrew-Black&userId=07609", "personName=Jane-Wells&userId=07610", "personName=John-Richards&userId=07611"]
like this right??

Comment: Yes, that's right - do you mean I need have $scope.download = function() { $http.get("localhost:3000/download?"+ $scope.selection[ ]) .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { }); };

Comment: No it doesn't:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]  But thanks for your help :)

Comment: i didnt write anything like that. Please check my answer

Comment: Yes just tried it. Sorry, it doesn't work - thanks again for your help.

Comment: There's no error, just doesn't bring anything back.